# Django CKEditor Background Color

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm using django ckeditor, and when i click any button (for example: iframe button), the background color is black so its hard to see and edit

[image]

Here is my code for django ckeditor config

```
    CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': [["Format", "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "SpellChecker"],
                    ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', "Indent", "Outdent", 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter',
                     'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
                    ["Image", "Table", "Link", "Unlink", "Anchor", "SectionLink",
                        "Subscript", "Superscript", "Iframe"], ['Undo', 'Redo'],
                    ["Maximize"]],
    },
}
```

Is there a way to change a color background? Is the problem in django ckeditor? django? or my browser? any idea?
Thankyou.

Comment: Solved this problem, how?

Comment: I haven't found the answer yet

Comment: One of the solutions is to change the color of Django Admin. I used django-admin-interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch off your browsers "dark mode", it should work.

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions is use to use a admin ui, such as simpleui